# Calling overloaded base constructor from derived class

Tags: c++, c++11

If I understand correctly, the base class constructor is always called with creating an object of the derived class.  Is there a way to call an overloaded base class constructor when creating the derived object?

Comment: Are you familiar with constructor initializer lists at all?

Comment: Use constuctor's initialization lists

Comment: Alok:  Not really a dupe.  This question asks "how do I do X", and the answer is "use Y."  That question asks "What is Y" but does not really elaborate on how it solves X.  Reading the linked question may only serve to confuse, not clarify, until the OP knows what Y is.

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with it, but I will be soon.  I tried searching for this answer, but could not quite find what I was looking for.  Sorry.

Comment: Voting to reopen for reasons I elaborated above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, via an initialization list:

```
class Base
{
public:
  Base (int n) : mN(n) {}
private:
  int mN;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived() : Base (42) {};
         // ^^^^^^^^^^^    
         // Initialization List
};
```

For more about the initialization list syntax, see this question:

[What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with that.

Comment: Note that this is not like in C#, where Base is what you have to write there (exactly that). Base would be the name of the Base class.